# How to solve this override UITextField values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have created iOS new app. `UITextField` is added in each row of `UITableView`. first row `UITextField` enter values then add new row the first row `UITextField` values show in second row `UITextField`. how to solve this issues.  please help me . thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code add row functionality

```
- (IBAction)btnAddRow:(id)sender {
    [self loadData:[self.dataArray count]];

    [self.tblview reloadData];
}

-(void ) loadData:(NSInteger) Indexvalue
{
    newSheet = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strEntryID,entryID, nil];
    [self.dataArray insertObject:newSheet atIndex:Indexvalue];    
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }   
        UITextField *txtComment =  [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0f,5.0f,50.0f,20.0f)];
        [txtComment setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
        [cell addSubview:txtComment];
        [txtComment setTag:indexPath.row];
        [txtComment addTarget:self action:@selector(txtCommentChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]; 
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please use a more specific question title, andexplain exactly what your problem is.

Comment: where u set value in textfield ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)btnAddRow:(id)sender {
    [self loadData:[self.dataArray count]];

    [self.tblview reloadData];
}

-(void ) loadData:(NSInteger) Indexvalue
{
    newSheet = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strEntryID,entryID, nil];
    [self.dataArray insertObject:newSheet atIndex:Indexvalue];    
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }   
    for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }

        UITextField *txtComment =  [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0f,5.0f,50.0f,20.0f)];
        [txtComment setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
        [cell addSubview:txtComment];
        [txtComment setTag:indexPath.row];
        [txtComment addTarget:self action:@selector(txtCommentChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]; 
     return cell;
}
```

You write just one for loop after your cell allocation.

Answer (score 0):

txtComment.text = yourText

You missed it

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new UITextField every time that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.  Cells are re-used as you scroll, so imagine that as a cell goes off the top of the screen, its quickly taken and put at the bottom of the screen to be the new cell that is appearing.  This also means that if you added a textfield first time round, then a second one will be added on top of the first.

If you add your UITextField within the same if statement where you initialize your cell, this will prevent more than one textfield appearing.  Eg :

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    UITextField *txtComment =  [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0f,5.0f,50.0f,20.0f)];
    [txtComment setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
    [cell addSubview:txtComment];
    [txtComment setTag:indexPath.row];
    [txtComment addTarget:self action:@selector(txtCommentChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}
```

Theres also a method you can use that is called when a cell is about to be recycled : -prepareForReuse.  This is called on the UITableViewCell itself though, so you would need a subclass of UITableViewCell to access it.

```
- (void) prepareForReuse {
    //set text fields to @"" for eg
}
```